# Creating Folders From File Name and Save the Files. But First Folder always goes in problem

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I have changed the way of working with Uploads.
I noticed when I select a folder to upload it selects all inner files even from sub-folders and in my main folder there are many sub folders and in every sub folder, there are are 2 to 3 files.
File Names are as following.

```
6-AALIYAH WIGHTON - 299-SOLO-JAZZ-6 YEARS AND UNDER
7-ABIGAIL PALMER - 301-SOLO-LYRICAL-6 YEARS AND UNDER
4-ZOE CAMPBELL - 299-SOLO-JAZZ-6 YEARS AND UNDER.mp3
```

So, in file names the 2nd parameter is the folder name.
Like, in above 3 sample names, `AALIYAH WIGHTON`, `ABIGAIL PALMER` & `ZOE CAMPBELL` are folder names. Which needs to be created first and then files will go inside these folders.

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
        if(strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
            $Folder = explode('-', $name)[1];
            $Path = 'BaberZamanTest/TEST/'.trim($Folder);
            
            //First Make Directories or Folder if not exist
            if(!file_exists($Path)){
            mkdir($Path, 0777, true);
            }
            //If the Folder has no file $name in $Path then Move file 
            if(!file_exists($Path.'/'.$name)){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $Path.'/'.$name);
            }
        }
    }
}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple webkitdirectory mozdirectory>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Now what is the issue.
Overall it is working perfect. But every time it skips first folder, Or some files in first folder.
When I select my folder it shows correct number of files. In folder there are `10` Sub folders and all sub folders have `22` total files in all. When I select, It shows correct number of files `22` but when upload process runs, it often uploads `20` files. Specially it misses the first folder only. all other folders work perfect. All files come there.

Kindly help me in this issue

Comment: Hopefully your system doesn't fail if someone has a name with `-` in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to edit your `php.ini` file first. Because the default number of `max_file_uploads` is `20` and I am damn sure you have missed this part.

Go to you `public_html` and locate `php.ini` file. You can create a new `php.ini` file if not exists, edit it with text editor and put there

```
max_file_uploads=50;
```

or what number of files you want.

It will work